# How to filter by custom field in django admin, the value of which is calculated

Tags: python, django-models, django-admin, celery, django-admin-filters

I have a task to calculate the status of the celery task and display it in the admin panel, as well as add filtering by statuses, all my errors lead to an error that says that the database does not have a status field.

I also wrote a custom filter

```
class TaskStatusFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'status'
    parameter_name = 'status' 

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):  
        return (
            ('success', 'SUCCESS'),
            ('failure', 'FAILURE'),
            ('pending', 'PENDING'),
            ('started', 'STARTED'),
            ('retry', 'RETRY'),
            ('revoked', 'REVOKED'),
            ("timeout", "TIMEOUT"),
            ('started_on_retry', 'STARTED_ON_RETRY')
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):  
        if self.value() == 'SUCCESS':
            queryset = queryset.filter(status='SUCCESS')
        elif self.value() == 'FAILURE':
            queryset = queryset.filter(status='FAILURE')
        elif self.value() == 'PENDING':
            queryset = queryset.filter(status='PENDING')
        elif self.value() == 'STARTED':
            queryset = queryset.filter(status='STARTED')
        elif self.value() == 'RETRY':
            queryset = queryset.filter(status='RETRY')
        elif self.value() == 'REVOKED':
            queryset = queryset.filter(status='REVOKED')
        elif self.value() == 'TIMEOUT':
            queryset = queryset.filter(status='TIMEOUT')
        elif self.value() == 'STARTED_ON_RETRY':
            queryset = queryset.filter(status='STARTED_ON_RETRY')
        return queryset
```

But queryset does not contain status

Here is the function of getting the status

```
def status(self, obj):
    status = get_task_status(obj.task_uuid)
    return status
```